# Can I safely change data in a replicated SQL Server table on the target machine?

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I replicate a table from one SQL Server 2008 instance to another which already works fine. I'd also like to set a field in the replicated table on the **target instance** of the SQL Servers, but I'm not quite sure whether this is allowed (even though it seems to work).

Reason behind this: Replication from server A to B, processing of rows on server B and then setting (e.g. a flag such as "processed") when the row has been processed. This information is not available on server A and can only be set on server B.

A more cumbersome way would involve a separate table on server B which would have to keep entries of IDs in the replicated table that have already been processed, but maybe this is not necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Transactional Replication, by default the Subscribers should be treated as read-only.  This is because if data has been changed at a Subscriber - whether it be inserts, updated, or deletes - it can not only cause data consistency errors, but a reinitialization could wipe the Subscriber data out as article **@pre_creation_cmd** is set to **drop** by default.

If you're going to be updating data at the Subscribers then I would suggest using [Updatable Subscriptions for Transactional Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151718.aspx), [Peer to Peer Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196.aspx), or [Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx).